# how to do event handling on BOTH overlapped HTMLs elements

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

How do I allow click event to "click through" layers.
aka. have the event fire on BOTH overlapped elements of different layers.

`sandbox link: http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5zd/`

so that if i click on the center, i have aba AND aaa fired.
is the a universal solutions to virtually infinite layers complexity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: First try to search for similar problem you are facing and if you can not find anything like yours then post the problem.

Comment: again~ 
pointer-events: none; 
can't help if i want event fire in  BOTH divs